# Square root approximation Clojure

Tags: clojure, rounding, approximation, square-root

I am getting an error and do not know how to fix it. I have to calculate square root with approximation and it should stop on the 20th element.

- Unable to resolve symbol: aprox in this context, compiling:(/home/jdoodle.clj:2:2)

Code:

```
(defn msqrt [n]
    (aprox  (n 1.0 1)))
(defn aprox [n prox part]
(if (= part 20)
    prox
(+ (/ n (* 2 (aprox n part (+ part 1)))) (/ (aprox n prox (+ part 1))2)))
)
(msqrt 9)
```

Comment: This will still fail after you make the suggested change. You're attempting to call `n` as a function in `msqrt`. Not sure what you're trying to do there. Do you mean just `(aprox n 1.0 1)`?

Comment: Very true --^^.  My answer is only the direct answer to that error, not a complete fix for your code.

Comment: Just comment about the recursive code. It will be very slow.  I suggest you try to use a tail-recursive solution.

    (defn newt
      ([n] (newt n 1.0 20))
      ([n guess step]
       (if (zero? step)
         guess
         (recur n (/ (+ guess (/ n guess)) 2.0) (dec step)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clojure, the order you declare functions in matters.  They don't get hoisted up like in Javascript.  You can fix this by either:

1. Moving your `defn aprox` above `defn msqrt`
2. Adding `declare aprox` to the top of your file to make it available

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/declare

Answer (score 0):

The [corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352010/1562315) answer compiles, but, but does not do what it ought to. The first reference to `part` in the `aprox` function ought to be to `prox`:

```
(defn aprox [n prox part]
  (if (= part 20)
      prox
      (+
        (/ n (* 2 (aprox n prox (inc part))))
        (/ (aprox n prox (inc part)) 2))))
```

I've taken the chance to improve layout and brevity.

It works:

```
> (msqrt 9)
=> 3.0
```

But it makes the same recursive call twice. It only need do so once:

```
(defn aprox [n prox part]
  (if (= part 20)
      prox
      (let [deeper-prox (aprox n prox (inc part))]
        (+
          (/ n (* 2 deeper-prox))
          (/ deeper-prox 2)))))
```

There are now about twenty recursive calls instead of about a million (2^20).

And we can see how this works. In the recursive call,

- the `part` argument counts up to `20`, creating a call stack twenty
  deep;
- the `prox` argument uses the recursion to generate and
  return an improved estimate of itself;
- the `n` argument is passed on unaltered.

We can get the same effect by repeating the improvement process twenty times and folding it into the `msqrt` function:

```
(defn msqrt [n]
  (loop [prox 1.0, part 20]
    (if (pos? part)
      (recur (+ (/ n (* 2 prox)) (/ prox 2)) (dec part))
      prox)))
```